# Show custom image if it exist else show different image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I'm trying to show a custom image and if it doesn't exist to show the regular image and not a placeholder.  No matter what I try so far I get image not found exception error. Here is one of my attempts:

```
    <?php $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
    <?php $custom_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'custom_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE); ?>
    <?php $regular_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE); ?>            
    <?php if ($custom_image != ''): ?>
    <?php echo $custom_image; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $regular_image; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

As long as there is a image it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php if($product->getCustomImage()):?>
   <?php $custom_image =  Mage::helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($product,'custom_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)
    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE); ?>
   <?php echo $custom_image; ?>
 <?php else: ?>
    <?php $regular_image =  Mage::helper('catalog/image')
     ->init($product,'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)
     ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE); ?>
    <?php echo $regular_image; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried it and get the same exception error on line (14) image not found. Line 14 is <?php $custom_image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'custom_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE); ?> I guess because it's outside the if statement.

Comment: i wanna know what is the custom_image that u are trying  to show. It's related to product ?

Comment: Yes, it's a image I have in admin under product images. Special image for Pinterest. But many items don't have it.

Comment: @Freejoy i just edit my answer try it and tell me if it works

Comment: I tried it and get this error:  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPinterestImage() on null .

Comment: I did.  I tried this before a couple years ago and never could get it working. But here I am plugging away.

Comment: let's continue talking on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80521/discussion-between-sami23-and-freejoy